# Instr in vba not working with a formula cell

Tags: excel, vba, instr

I have a cell (example L22) with has a formula (which refers to another sheet (Sheet!1A22) and returns a value sale 110 (108%). I wanted to change the text color of (108%) only (and not the entire cell value). My approach was to use Instr to find "(" and find the length till ")" and color it. This is the code I used.

```
Sub colr()
Dim StartChar As Integer, LenColor As Integer
    With Flash.Range("L22")
        StartChar = InStr(1, .Value, "(")
        If StartChar <> 0 Then
            LenColor = Len(.Value) - StartChar + 1
            .Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=LenColor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If

    End With
End Sub
```

but the code does not do anything. But if I replace the formula with value, it works fine.

Comment: You *can't* do this if there's a formula in the cell.

Comment: then what is the alternative to this?

Comment: There is no alternative unfortunately, if you have to use a formula.

Comment: I'm afraid that Instr works very well in a formula cell... But you cannot color characters in such a volatile string.

Comment: get value of formula cell and if it's a number, convert it to string first

Comment: Can you please tell me how?

Comment: Check the value with msgbox or debug.print

Comment: you said sheet L22 returns a value sale 110, but you do instr to find "(", so here you not clearly, L22 value is string or number.

Comment: please screen shoot your L22

Comment: And please explain, how do you call sub colr()? Manually or by sheet change event?

Comment: It will be called when a user clicks a button.

Comment: The formula in L22 is = sheet1! A22 ( just an example) and the value it gives is 110(108%). So basically all the calculation happens on A22.

Answer (score 0):

As others have commented, it's not possible to manipulate `Characters` in the result of a formula - at least not as far as I know.

The most obvious alternative is to write the value and percentage in two adjacent cells and then use conditional formatting on the latter.

However, if you're stuck with the format that you have, then you're going to have to work around the formula issue. A formula calculation is basically triggered when any referenced range value is changed. You could capture that event yourself, say in a `Worksheet_Change` handler and write the result of your algorithm to Sheet2. This would enable you to colour the characters of the result.

Skeleton code would look like this (in your Sheet1 object):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim pt As Long

    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        'Test for a change in the desired range.
        If Not Intersect(cell, Me.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then
            'Check that your cell value matches the conditions you want, eg
            If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
                'Calculate the result - as per your cell formula.
                result = cell.Value * 2 & " (" & cell.Value * 2 / 100 & "%)"
                'Write and colour the result.
                pt = InStr(result, "(")
                With Sheet2.Cells(cell.Row, "L")
                    .Value = result
                    .Characters(pt, Len(result)).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                End With
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am lost here. Can u please guide me? Like are we hard coding the numner into the cell instead of the formula?

Comment: No, you leave your L column cells blank. When a value is changed in Sheet1 column "A", the result of your formula (that's the line `result = cell.Value ...` but you must change this line to be your own formula) is written into the L column cell. I'd say that handling the `_change` event is reasonably advanced VBA work, so if you're finding the code difficult to understand, this solution might not be appropriate. The main problem will be for you to maintain it if the formulas or cell mapping (ie "A" to "L") changes.

Answer (score 0):

when you use value, so it will give you actual number, but with text, it will give you display in cell. So you can change:

```
StartChar = InStr(1, .Value, "(")
```

to be:

```
StartChar = InStr(1, .text, "(")
```

Comment: If so please check the value of Flash.Range("L22").value with msgbox or debug.print

Comment: What is type value in L22, string or number, if number how do you format it?